# How to use the resultset of two queries as parameter for third query in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Hello Neo4J/Cypher Gurus.

I need to get the result set of two queries and use them as a parameter for a third one.
I was able to use the resut set of one (or the other) query as a parameter for the third one, but both queries as same time doesn't work.

I'm trying:

```
// External Parameter
:params {extParam:'1.1.1'}
// First Query
MATCH p=(startnode:DerivTree)-[:IsDerivedFrom*0..]->(endnode:DerivTree)
  WHERE startnode.dbvid=$extParam
  UNWIND nodes(p) as query1_list
  WITH distinct query1_list.dbvid as query1_result
// Second Query
MATCH (d:Resource {deleted:true})
  WHERE d.dbvid=$extParam
  WITH COLLECT(d) AS query2_list
  UNWIND query2_list as query2_result
// Third Query
MATCH (n:Resource)
  WHERE n.prop1 = query1_result
    AND n.prop2 <> query2_result
    AND EXISTS(n.prop3)
  RETURN n
```

If I try Query 1 and Query 3 (without the filter that uses Query 2 result set) it works.
If I try Query 2 and Query 3 (without the filter that uses Query 1 result set) it also works.

But I need Query 1 and 2 result sets on the Query 3's filter.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating cartesian products between your variables. If you PROFILE your query you should see how the number of rows flowing between the operations increases as your query progresses.

Also, you dropped `query1_result` out of scope since you didn't include it in the WITH in the second query. WITH changes out what's in scope; if you want it to keep being in scope, you need to include it.

To fix this, you'll likely want to make sure you collect your results along the way (such as collecting the results of your first query so cardinality drops to 1 to avoid multiplicatively executing the next operations), then do the same for query 2, and if you do need the results as rows, unwind them for query 3 (though in your case using `in` for list membership should be enough).

Give this a try:

```
// First Query
MATCH p=(startnode:DerivTree)-[:IsDerivedFrom*0..]->(endnode:DerivTree)
WHERE startnode.dbvid=$extParam
UNWIND nodes(p) as query1 // this is not a list, so rename the variable
WITH collect(distinct query1.dbvid) as query1_results // cardinality at 1 row
// Second Query
MATCH (d:Resource {deleted:true})
WHERE d.dbvid=$extParam
WITH query1_results, COLLECT(d) AS query2_results // cardinality at 1 row
// Third Query
MATCH (n:Resource)
WHERE n.prop1 in query1_results
  AND not n.prop2 in query2_results
  AND EXISTS(n.prop3)
RETURN n
```

Comment: Many thanks. It worked perfectly however, as you pointed, it is really increasing the number of rows while query is progressing.
I executed the PROFILE and generated a .png file, but I'm not sure how to add it to the post.

What should I do to avoid the cartesian product?

Comment: The above query should avoid it. Mainly, this is about awareness of how cardinality works in cypher queries, that operations produce rows, and subsequent operations execute per row, and lastly not to treat matched variables as collections (unless you actually `collect()` them). So `(d:Director)-[:DIRECTED]->(:Movie{title:'The Matrix'})<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Actor)` will produce a cartesian product between the directors and the actors (with the Matrix in common for each row). `d` and `a` are not collections. You would need to explicitly collect them to aggregate and reduce the cardinality.